# Variable product prices not showing in woocommerce front-end

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a woocommerce shop in which I sell products with color/size variations. Next to that I also use Woocommerce product add-ons to enable users to input a name that will be embroided on their product. I neatly input al the product variations like so:

[image: product variations]

After publishing the product it doesn't show any price though. How is this possible? A screenshot of how the product is shown on the front-end:

[image: product as shown in the front-end]

the plugins and add-ons I use for WooCommerce:

- WooCommerce Product Add-ons
- WooCommerce Print Invoice & Delivery Note
- WooCommerce Variation Swatches and Photos

Answer (score 0):

The default functionality of WooCommmerce pluging for WordPress is that it doesn't show the price for variable products.

As there are many variations and each variation have different pricing a drop down list is provide to select a variations. So only after selecting a particular variation prices for the same will be display.

Try adding sale prices for all variations. And check whether the pricing range of the variable product is shown or not on front-end or not.

A link to this page would be more helpful to debug your problem.